# I got a error while sending mail using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

the error is The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t77sm26908892pfg.102 - gsmtp

```
          Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
        Net.NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "user1")
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("user@gmail.com")

            mail.To.Add("user2@gmail.com")
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send")
```

Comment: UseSSL true, theres a property to ssl; set that to true...

Comment: in my code there is no ssl

Comment: thanq u sir for u r replay

Answer (score 1):

As Codexer said in his comment, you are not enabling SSL by setting `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True`

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
SmtpServer.Port = 587
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True ' <---- this
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
Net.NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "user1")
mail = New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("user@gmail.com")
mail.To.Add("user2@gmail.com")
mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
SmtpServer.Send(mail)
MsgBox("mail send")
```

It always a good idea to not send your credentials as plain text over the internet...